# SQLiteFullException: database or disk is full (code 13) GreenDao

Tags: android, android-sqlite, greendao

how to solving SQLiteFulException in greenDao when I delete record from table?

this is my stacktrace :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteFullException: database or disk is full (code 13)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:555)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:437)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:522)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.deleteInTxInternal(AbstractDao.java:613)
at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.deleteInTx(AbstractDao.java:623)
```

this is my code for delete record from database :

```
QueryBuilder<TaskD> qb = getTaskDDao(context).queryBuilder();
qb.where(TaskDDao.Properties.Uuid_task_h.eq(keyTaskH));
qb.build();
getTaskDDao(context).deleteInTx(qb.list());
getDaoSession(context).clear();
```

Comment: Please post the code that you're using.

Comment: question was edited for code that i'am using @Egor

Answer (score 5):

This is unrelated to greenDAO. If your disk is full, it is full. You ran out of disk space. Depending on what you do, running VACUUM SQLite occasionally may defrag your DB.

Comment: is there the ability from GreenDao for setting schema.auto_vacuum in the database, @greenrobot ?

Comment: No, greenDAO does not touch vacuum at all

Answer (score 2):

From SQLite documentation

(13) SQLITE_FULL

The SQLITE_FULL result code indicates that a write could not complete because the disk is full. Note that this error can occur when trying to write information into the main database file, or it can also occur when writing into temporary disk files.
Sometimes applications encounter this error even though there is an abundance of primary disk space because the error occurs when writing into temporary disk files on a system where temporary files are stored on a separate partition with much less space that the primary disk.
https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#full

I guess application is installed on SDCARD or something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of error codes https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html

```
(13) SQLITE_FULL
The SQLITE_FULL result code indicates that a write could not complete because the 
disk is full. Note that this error can occur when trying to write information into 
the main database file, or it can also occur when writing into temporary disk files.

Sometimes applications encounter this error even though there is an abundance of 
primary disk space because the error occurs when writing into temporary disk files on 
a system where temporary files are stored on a separate partition with much less 
space that the primary disk.`
```

And here is the temporary files used by sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html
Are you receiving too much data from server maybe?